# Trow error when trying to make new vue-cli webpack project

Tags: vue.js

I keep getting a throw error with permission denied when trying to make a new vue-cli webpack build. It worked last night, but now all of a sudden I get these errors. Anyone know how to fix this?

```
    /usr/local/lib/node_modules/vue-cli/node_modules/rimraf/rimraf.js:312
        throw er
        ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, unlink
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're running this command on Linux; try using `chown` to give yourself permission to access all of those directories / files.

See also: [GitHub - Bower - EACCES: permission denied](https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/2262)

Comment: Didnt help. Im running it on a mac. Its strange because when I tried doing the vue-cli webpack install last night it worked fine. But now it keeps giving me these errors. I even tried reinstalling vue, vue-cli, node, npm... but nothing helps. I can still do vue-cli webpack-simple though.

Comment: sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.npm

Comment: That command was for the problem that other guy was having; you'll want to try to run something like `chmod -R 777 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/`.

Comment: Didnt help... sorry. 
I did a vue init webpack [project.name] --offline instead, and it works.

Answer (score 2):

I was also getting this kind of error:

```
downloading template
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-init/node_modules/rimraf/rimraf.js:313
        throw er
        ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/home/apoorv/.vue-templates/webpack/.gitignore'
    at Object.unlinkSync (fs.js:956:3)
    at rimrafSync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-init/node_modules/rimraf/rimraf.js:306:17)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-init/node_modules/rimraf/rimraf.js:342:5
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at rmkidsSync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-init/node_modules/rimraf/rimraf.js:341:26)
    at rmdirSync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-init/node_modules/rimraf/rimraf.js:334:7)
    at rimrafSync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-init/node_modules/rimraf/rimraf.js:304:9)
    at downloadAndGenerate (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-init/node_modules/vue-cli/bin/vue-init:149:20)
    at checkVersion (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-init/node_modules/vue-cli/bin/vue-init:130:11)
    at Request.request [as _callback] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-init/node_modules/vue-cli/lib/check-version.js:29:5)
    at Request.self.callback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-init/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22)
    at Request.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-init/node_modules/request/request.js:1161:10)
    at Request.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-init/node_modules/request/request.js:1083:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:286:20)
```

It seemed like I didn't have appropriate permissions to

> /home/apoorv/.vue-templates/webpack/.gitignore

Following @Nathan Wailes' answer, I just changed the permissions and resolved my issue using:

```
chmod -R 777 /home/apoorv/.vue-templates/*
```